# Navigate HTML table rows with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML table that has an onclick event in the first column in each row that will load content when pressed. I want to navigate through the table with the up and down arrow keys and when I press enter, fire off the oncliick event. I do not need to navigate cells, just the rows to highlight the row so you know which row's content is being displayed. Heres my table:

```
<table class="table_id">
    <thead style="background: #DAE6F0;">
      <th width="49"></th>
      <th width="106">Location</th>
      <th width="107">SelectionType</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.List)
    {
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 49px;"><a onclick=" getTeplate(@item.Id); ">Display</a></td>
        <td style="width: 120px; text-align: center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdvertisementLocation)</td>
        <td style="width: 107px; text-align: center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdvertisementSelectionType)</td>
      </tr>
    }
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

My CSS is set up to make the table a set height with a scroll bar:

```
tbody {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      overflow: auto;
      max-height: 486px;
}

thead, tbody {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: block;
}

th {

    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

I would like to do this all with JS. Andy Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can [see a solution using JavaScript and jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/h68240qd/3/) (**note**: I changed the table from `class="table_id"` to `id="table_id"` for convenience):

```
var isTableActive = false;

// every time that there's a click, detect if it was on the table or outside of it
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    isTableActive = $.contains(document.getElementById("table_id"), e.target);
});

// the first row will be active by default
$("#table_id tbody tr:first-child").addClass("active");

// focus the clicked row (no need to scroll because it's visible
$("#table_id tbody tr").on("click", function() {
    $("#table_id tbody tr.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

// when a key is pressed
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {

    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 38: // up
            if ($("#table_id tbody tr.active").prev().length) {
                $("#table_id tbody tr.active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
            }
            break;
        case 40: // down
            if ($("#table_id tbody tr.active").next().length) {
                $("#table_id tbody tr.active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
            }
            break;
        case 13: // enter
            $("#table_id tbody tr.active").find("a").click();
            break;
    }

    // the selected element will always be visible on top
    $("#table_id tbody").scrollTop(
        $("#table_id tbody tr.active").offset().top + 
        $("#table_id tbody").scrollTop() - 
        $("#table_id tbody").offset().top
    );

    // prevent the scrolling effect if the last active element was the table
    if (isTableActive) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Optionally, you can add some CSS to highlight the active row, this will help you know which row action will be triggered:

```
#table_id tbody tr.active {
    background:#f0f0f0;
}
```

You can [see it working on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h68240qd/3/).

Comment: Since my table is larger than the max height it renders with a scroll bar. How would I set the focus so that it knows to scroll down once I go lower than the displayed rows?

Comment: Also there is another issue with clicking into the table. I would need to add JS to detect what row has been clicked and set focus to it. Right now with your code, if you click into the table the arrow keys only control the the scrolling of the table. If your answer could be updated to reflect those changes it would better suit for future viewers

Comment: The scrolling is done automatically if you click on the table (I may tweak the code a bit so it scrolls without clicking on the table), and for the row clicking and setting the focus, I've updated the solution (see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/h68240qd/1/)

Comment: Thank you! The scrolling is a bit off, correct, and on a list of say 50+ it becomes way off, but I will try to tweak, only other thing is off of initial load, the scroll feature does not work. You can see this in your edited jsfidle if you click on the header and then use the arrow keys, once outside the view it doesnt scroll

Comment: in JSFiddle its better, not perfect! For my application however, my <tr> height is much smaller and it still scrolls to far. For the sake of answering the question you've done great.

Comment: I think I just saw the problem. When you click on the table, the scrolling event (when pressing up/down) is done after I set the scroll to the position. If you click outside the table, it works fine. I'll modify it a little to detect if the last element clicked was within the table, and then prevent the annoying table scroll

Comment: I fixed the scrolling issue by preventing the scrolling when the last active element was the table, and updated the code in the solution. You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/h68240qd/3/

Comment: Weird I see it working is JSfiddle, but when I implement it in my code, and change from class to id on the table, it doesn't work at all. On load it doesn't even highlight the first row

Comment: You have to update the CSS too (before it used `.table_id` now it should be `#table_id`). It may be selected but you don't see it. Also, if it works on jsfiddle but not when you put it in your code, it's probably just a matter of adapting it better to your code.

Comment: I have made the needed adaptations, however, how does isTableActive work in the function. how does the following code set it to true or false, as it is not working in my code

Comment: It is all in the jsfiddle, it is commented to make it easier to understand what each part does, and it is working. There are many reasons why it could be failing on your side: are we using the same variable names for different things? did you mistype something? are there errors in the console log?... There is no way for me to know why it's failing in your code without seeing it... and that would be outside of the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it with Jquery, css and just a normal html table.
It's about as little code as clean of a solution as i could get it.

http://jsfiddle.net/vsgkjssq/5/

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/vsgkjssq/9/ passes the row index to the row click event and alerts what row is being clicked

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/vsgkjssq/11/ Clamps the number of rows, uses keydown to hold the button and fly through the rows.

Jquery

```
$(function () {
    var index = 1;
    var rows = $('tr');

    // initial load add the selected class to the first non header row
    $(rows[index]).addClass('selected');

    $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {       

        // clear the selected class off of the row
        $(rows[index]).removeClass('selected');

        // increment/decrement the index
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 40: // down
                index++;
                break;
            case 38: // up
                index--;
                break;
            case 13: // enter
                $(rows[index]).click();
                break;
        }

        // adds the "selected" class to all tds in the row
        $(rows[index]).addClass('selected');        
    }); 

    $('tr').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

and here's the css..

```
* {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:'Verdana', Arial, Sans-Serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 10px;
}
table tr.selected td {
    background: #4679bd;
}
table, th, td {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
th {
    background: #0f4871;
    color: #fff;
}
tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Comment: I like your progression of jsfiddle solutions.... the final jsfiddle v11 is my favorite by far.

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $('#table_id > tbody');
var height = table.children().length;
var curRow = 0; //Current row we've navigated to

$("body").on("keydown", function(e){
    if (/* we are currently navigating the table */) {
        //Check up, down keys for navigation
        if (e.keyCode === 38) { //up
            curRow--;
        } 
        else if (e.keyCode === 40) { //down
            curRow++;    
        } 

        if (curRow < 0) curRow = 0;
        else if (curRow >= height) curRow = height - 1;

        var trElem = table.children().eq(curRow);
        var tdElem = trElem.children(':first-child');

        /* 
        If you want to style the current tr or td, do it here
        using trElem and/or tdElem
        */

        //If the enter button is pressed, simulate a click on the current row
        if (e.keyCode === 13) { //enter
            tdElem.click();
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Basically, when the up/down keys are pressed increment/decrement some counter, then find the row at that counter's index, optionally style that row, and then when the enter button is pressed activate the same click function.

Comment: Do you have to place an identifier in this if statement? if (/* we are currently navigating the table */)

Comment: Of course! You didn't really specify anything about the greater application, but I just assume that you don't always want the up/down arrows to navigate around the table (because usually they're used for scrolling the page up/down) so if there are circumstances in which you don't want arrow keys to apply to the table, you can control it with that if. (Also, your comment reminded me of something I had missed - note my small edit, the "return false" statement)